# Is someone accessing my win10 computer?

Tags: attack-prevention, ports, incident-response, log-analysis, incident-analysis

I have been wondering if someone is accessing my system and after doing using some basic assessment tools like netstat and event viewer, found some unusual open ports(12345) and special Logon! below is the screenshots I would really appreciate if someone confirm this as I am not an expert in Cyber security.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piBkm.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post a screenshot of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: You can also show the listening processes using Resource Monitor's network tab, in the Listening Ports section, though TCPView is probably better.